# Insert and Delete statement using TOP 1

Tags: c#, sql

I'm writing a c# program for cinema. The program will move a user to waiting list if the movie fully booked. If someone cancelled the reservation for a movie, the top person the waiting list will be automatically moved to reservation list

I've have coding the part to move user to waiting list if full and it can work.
Now I'm stuck in the part to select the top user from waiting list and move them to reservation list. And delete the person's record from waiting list

This my sql for moving from waiting to reservation.

```
    string myQry = "INSERT INTO reserve (ID,M_ID,R_Date) VALUES (SELECT TOP 1 (ID,M_ID,R_Date) FROM Wait WHERE M_ID=)" + mID+ " (ORDER BY R_Date ASC)";
```

This sql to delete that person.

```
      string myQry= "DELETE FROM Wait WHERE M_ID IN SELECT TOP 1 M_ID FROM Wait WHERE M_ID =" + mid;
```

My other functions works perfectly and no error while compile and running the program. So I think, there must be a problem in my sql. Please help me thank you.

Comment: WARNING!! SQL INJECTION RISK ALERT!!!  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Assuming `mID` is an integer of some kind here?  If not, this could be an SQL injection...  Are you using transactions so the two statements don't occur seprately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO reserve (ID,M_ID,R_Date)
    VALUES (SELECT TOP 1 (ID,M_ID,R_Date) FROM Wait WHERE M_ID= . . .
```

I think you intend:

```
INSERT INTO reserve (ID,M_ID,R_Date)
    SELECT TOP 1 ID, M_ID, R_Date
    FROM Wait WHERE M_ID = . . .;
```

Both the parentheses around the column names are wrong as is the returning of multiple values from the `select` to the `values` clause.

I should add that what you are doing seems unsafe, due to potential timing conflicts.  You should investigate the `OUTPUT` clause.  One approach is to delete the record from `wait`, putting it in a temporary table, and then insert into `reserve`.

Comment: Thank you for replying...The Insert statement did worked. But Delete statement didn't work

Comment: I have updated the delete statement. Please look into it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'd need transactions to make this safe, but these adjustments may work:

```
string myQry = "INSERT INTO reserve (ID,M_ID,R_Date) "
             + " SELECT TOP 1 (ID,M_ID,R_Date) "
             + " FROM Wait WHERE M_ID=" + mID + " "
             + " ORDER BY R_Date ASC";
```

Then for delete:

```
string myQry = "DELETE FROM Wait WHERE ID IN "
             + " (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Wait WHERE M_ID =" + mID + " "
             + "  ORDER BY R_Date ASC)";
```

Note: It's probably better to retrieve an auto increment ID on the `Wait` table into a variable and then use it for the insert and delete queries, but I'm not sure which SQL Server API you're using to write an example of retrieving selected values.

PS - If `ID` is the user ID (which seems likely), you may want to rename it to something like `user_ID`.  Also, it would be best to use an auto increment ID in the `Wait` table for identifying just one row.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like

```
DELETE TOP (1) FROM Wait WHERE M_ID = mid
```

An order by here might be useful too.

Comment: You forgot the order by clause, but yeah that's actually the way to do it somewhat right given there's apparently no auto increment ID in use.

Answer (score 0):

You have redundant brackets:

```
... WHERE M_ID = " + mid + " ORDER BY R_Date ASC)";
```